# Gradle task :installGulp - error EEXIST with gulp.cmd file

Tags: gradle, npm, gulp

I have seen the questions on this site already with `npm install` giving the error above.

This is NOT the same question. In this case, the `:installGulp` task runs when I try to run my application(runs on its own; not part of my `build.gradle` file), and since `npm install` also installs Gulp from my npm dependencies, it finds the `gulp.cmd` file and complains thus:

```
npm ERR! path yourproject\node_modules\.bin\gulp.cmd
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete yourproject\node_modules\.bin\gulp.cmd: is outside yourproject\node_modules\gulp and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: yourproject\node_modules\.bin\gulp.cmd
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
```

Why doesn't it simply detect it and move on? Why crash?

For now, I have to manually rename the `gulp.cmd` file to something else to run the application. But I'm looking for a less brittle solution than this.

**NOTE**: There's also some differences between the old(`npm install` file) and new(`:installGulp` file) `gulp.cmd` files. This is for gulp version `4.0.2`.

Old `gulp.cmd`:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL
CALL :find_dp0

IF EXIST "%dp0%\node.exe" (
  SET "_prog=%dp0%\node.exe"
) ELSE (
  SET "_prog=node"
  SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
)

"%_prog%"  "%dp0%\..\gulp\bin\gulp.js" %*
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /b %errorlevel%
:find_dp0
SET dp0=%~dp0
EXIT /b
```

New `gulp.cmd`:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\..\gulp\bin\gulp.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\..\gulp\bin\gulp.js" %*
)
```

Comment: Sounds like the dp0 path is not set in the new file. Have you tried adding/using the old the code?

Comment: @cascading-jox Yes, no difference. And these files are generated by `npm install`, not manually.